# OpenGL doesn't draw anything

Tags: c++, opengl

From what I checked it should work, even my vertex and fragment shaders are copied from a tutorial site which have worked for others and for other codes but I think there's something in my code that I probably don't notice that makes my program behave that way.

this is the Initialize code of the drawable:

```
// before the draw function:
std::vector<glm::vec3> vertices;
  vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(-1, -1, 0)); vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(1, 0, 0)); vertices.push_back(glm::vec3(1, -1, 0));
  std::vector<glm::vec3> colors;
  colors.push_back(glm::vec3(1, 1, 0)); colors.push_back(glm::vec3(1, 1, 0)); colors.push_back(glm::vec3(1, 1, 0));

  test.Initialize(vertices, colors);

// The Initialize function in the 'Drawable' class

void Drawable::Initialize(std::vector< glm::vec3 > vertex, std::vector< glm::vec3 > color)
{
  // Check if the drawables had been initialized, if not, Initialize it, else return an error
  if(hasInit)
    std::cerr << "[-] Already Initialized";
  else
  {
    hasInit = true;
    vertices = vertex;
    colors = color;

    //Generate buffers and bind the object to OpenGL then bind the data for opengl to read from
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &colorBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colors.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &colors[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Calculate the model-view-projection matrix for later use
    MVP = settings->projection * settings->camera * model;
  }
}
```

And in the draw function which loops of course:

```
// Calling the draw function for the Drawable class
test.Draw();

// The draw function in the Drawable class
void Drawable::Draw()
{
  glUseProgram(settings->simpleProgramID);
  glUniformMatrix4fv(settings->mMVPLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0][0]);

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(settings->mVertexPositionLocation);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
  glVertexAttribPointer(settings->mVertexPositionLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

  glEnableVertexAttribArray(settings->mVertexColorLocation);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBuffer);
  glVertexAttribPointer(settings->mVertexColorLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(settings->mVertexColorLocation);
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(settings->mVertexPositionLocation);
}
```

Before the initialize function I get all the uniform and attribute location that I need and I store them in a struct called settings (a global struct that anyone can access, I even checked to make sure that the values in every other file are matched for the struct)

and these are my shaders:

```
// Vertex Shader
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 positionVertex;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 colorVertex;

uniform mat4 MVP;

out vec3 oColor;

void main(void)
{
  gl_Position = MVP * vec4(positionVertex, 1);
  oColor = colorVertex;
}

// Fragment Shader
#version 330 core

in vec3 oColor;
out vec3 color;

void main(void)
{
  color = oColor;
}
```

But nothing is drawn on the screen, does someone notice something unusual?
I initialized the all the matrices as glm::mat4(1.0f) which is the identity matrix.
I have debugged the code and everything seems to run smoothly but still no result.

EDIT: 
I found that my compiler actually returns an error when trying to compile the vertex shader:

```
GLuint loadShaderes(const char* vertex_shader_file, const char* fragment_shader_file)
{
  GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
  GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

  std::string vertexShaderCode;
  std::ifstream vertexShaderStream(vertex_shader_file, std::ios::in);
  if(vertexShaderStream.is_open())
  {
    std::string Line = "";
    while(getline(vertexShaderStream, Line))
      vertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
    vertexShaderStream.close();
  }
  else
    return ERR_OPEN_VERTEX_FILE;

  std::string fragmentShaderCode;
  std::ifstream fragmentShaderStream(fragment_shader_file, std::ios::in);
  if(fragmentShaderStream.is_open())
  {
    std::string Line = "";
    while(getline(fragmentShaderStream, Line))
      fragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
    fragmentShaderStream.close();
  }
  else
    return ERR_OPEN_FRAGMENT_FILE;

  GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
  int InfoLogLength;

  char const * VertexSourcePointer = vertexShaderCode.c_str();
  glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
  glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

  glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
  glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);

  if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
    std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    return ERR_INIT_VERTEX_CODE; // Here the code returns
  }

  char const * FragmentSourcePointer = fragmentShaderCode.c_str();
  glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
  glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

  glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
  glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);

  if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
    std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
    return ERR_INIT_FRAGMENT_CODE;
  }


  GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
  glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
  glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
  glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

  glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
  glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);

  if ( InfoLogLength > 0 ){
    std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage(InfoLogLength+1);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
    return ERR_LINK_PROGRAM;
  }

  glDetachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
  glDetachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);

  glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
  glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

  return ProgramID;
}
```

From glGetError() I get the value 1280.

Comment: Have you checked for any double buffering of your window & if so that you're swapping the buffer?

Comment: Yes I swap the buffers everything outside of that works fine

Comment: "I initialized the all the matrices as glm::mat4(1.0f) which is the identity matrix." - **everything** is set to 1.0f ?? As that isn't the same as an identity matrix. See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) - I should point out I know some OpenGL but not C++

Comment: glm::mat4(1.0f) returns the Identity matrix yes the one in the link of course, I checked it even to see if the value is correct

Comment: Did you try calling `glGetError()`? What type of context are you using?

Comment: I edited the posted and added all the bugs that I found + the return value of glGetError()

Comment: `glGetProgramInfoLog()` should give you a more descriptive error message.